# Jquery: Select class and insert ".attr(***)" into all of that same class

Tags: jquery, insert, append, attr

```
var str = $('.rating').html();
$.trim(str);
$('.rating').prepend.attr('class', 'rating-' + str.replace(/\s/g, ""));

<div class="rating">1</div>
<div class="rating">2</div>
<div class="rating">3</div>

Change to this:
<div class="rating-1">1</div>
<div class="rating-2">2</div>
<div class="rating-3">3</div>
```

How does .prepend work with .attr ? Seems I can't find any information about append and attr.

All I want to do is select an class and replace them with class-1, class-2, class-3 etc.

Comment: You'll need to include your HTML as well.

Comment: `prepend` doesn't work that way....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prepend and append operate on DOM elements, not strings.  Use removeClass and addClass to accomplish what you are trying to:

```
$('.rating').removeClass("rating").addClass(function () {
    return "rating-" + $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

Because your changing the attribute

```
attr('class'
```

I think you should use removeClass and addClass

```
var cnt = 1; 
$('.rating').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("rating");
    $(this).addClass("rating-" + cnt);
    cnt = ctn + 1;

});
```

I think it would do it, so each class rating will be replace by rating-n where n will increment by 1 each time you change a class

Comment: ah of course, that will loop thru all. thanks man will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

> The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last child, use .append()).

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

If you want to just replace a class, use $(element).addClass and $(element).removeClass, not prepend.